# ValidateCredentialClaims - Access Denied: Claims stored in the credentials did not match with the group claim for a group app

Tags: secure-store

We have some credentials stored in the secure store service application.
Both the secure store service and the credential itself have permissions for the web app pool account.

When I try to use  a webpart that reads the connection string from the secure store I get this error:

```
ValidateCredentialClaims - Access Denied: Claims stored in the credentials did not match with the group claim for a group app.
```

The problem is that this was working before, it just suddenly stopped working because we have not changed the configuration on this service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, sharepoint was upgraded from march cu to october cu when it happened, after the servr was restarted this problem was gone.